# ImportError: No module named appengine.ext while using docker

Tags: python, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I'm trying to get google.appengine.ext working in a docker image

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

RUN virtualenv /env

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ENV PYTHONPATH /app:/app/lib:/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine:$PYTHONPATH

ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

ADD . /app
```

If i do print(google.**path**) i get this

```
['/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google', '/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `google.appengine` module is baked into the first-generation Python (2.7) runtime. It's not available to install via `pip`, in the second-generation (3.7) runtime, or in any Docker environment.

The only way to use it is by writing and deploying a first-generation App Engine app.

Depending on what you're doing, you should be able to replace it with a client library call instead.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3 for more details.